# gdb/lldb call a function and break in it

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, gdb, lldb

I have a global function in a long run program :

```
int test()
{
    int a = 12;
    int c = 10;
    printf("a=%d",a);
    a += c ;
    printf("a=%d", a);
    return a;
}
```

I debug the program and break, then issue the following command:

```
(lldb) call test()
a=12a=22(int) $0 = 22
(lldb)
```

I want it to break in `test()` method every line after I hit `call test()`, not just return the result immediately. Anyone knows how to do it ?

------------------------------------ Answer Below ------------------------------------

@Jason Molenda 's answer is the right answer,use `expr -i0 -- test()` instead of `call test()`:

```
(lldb) b test
Breakpoint 1: 4 locations.
(lldb) expr -i0 -- test()
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 1.1.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb)
```

Now it break in `test()`, but raise an error!!! How to avoid the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expression` command in lldb (`call` is an alias for `expression`) takes a dozen or so options, one of them being whether lldb should stop on a breakpoint while executing the expression, `--ignore-breakpoints false`, or `-i false`, or `-i 0`.

```
(lldb) br s -n printf
Breakpoint 2: where = libsystem_c.dylib`printf, address = 0x00007fff89ee7930
(lldb) expr -- (void)printf("hi\n")
hi
(lldb) expr -i0 -- (void)printf("hi\n")
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 2.1.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
Process 15259 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xf0daf, 0x00007fff89ee7930 libsystem_c.dylib`printf, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    #0: 0x00007fff89ee7930 libsystem_c.dylib`printf
libsystem_c.dylib`printf:
-> 0x7fff89ee7930:  pushq  %rbp
   0x7fff89ee7931:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x7fff89ee7934:  pushq  %r15
   0x7fff89ee7936:  pushq  %r14
(lldb)
```

There was some thought put in to the default behavior (whether to stop on a breakpoint or not), and this seemed the behavior most people would expect.

As I said, the `call` command is just an alias for `expression`.  If you want to change the behavior of it, you can overwrite the alias with one of your own.  e.g. `command alias call expr -i false --` will do the trick.  You can put this in your `~/.lldbinit` file and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a joke? Just checked standard breakpoint to be sure:

```
(gdb) b test
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400671: file t.c, line 6.
(gdb) call test()

Breakpoint 2, test () at t.c:6
6       printf("a\n");
```

Comment: No, it's not a joke. In `lldb` (Xcode), I did as you answered above, it can't break every line.

Comment: Well, I get this: (gdb) call test()

Breakpoint 1, test () at t.c:5
5     int a = 12;
The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(test) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
(gdb)

Comment: Yes, it is normal. You can step line by line in this function, you can finish it. Expected behaviour, isn't it?